# Return if all values meet the criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return all rows that have records in the child table where all of them meet the criteria

```
T1:
1
2
3
4
5
```

T2:

```
T.ID  Id  Value
1     01  Apple
1     02  Banana
2     05  Grapes
2     07  Kiwi
2     08  Apple
3     04  Banana
3     06  Potato
4     10  Honeydew
4     11  Berries
5     14  Apple
5     15  Kiwi
5     16  Radish
```

I need to identify all ids in T1 which are Fruit in T2, 
T2.value in (Apple,grapes,banana,kiwi,honeydew,berries)
Desired Output:

```
1
2
4
```

I have tried this:

```
select t1.id from t1,t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t2.value  in ('Apple','Grapes','Banana','Kiwi','Honeydew','Berries')
```

but it doesnt return the output I need, it also returns #3&5.

Comment: How do you know which values are fruit?

Comment: I do explicit search for those values. let me add it in my question

Comment: You have a capitalization issue in your literals list. It looks like it should be `('Apple','Grapes','Banana','Kiwi','Honeydew','Berries')`.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want ids that have at least one row in `t2`

```
select t2.id
from t2
group by t2.id
having sum(case when t2.value not in ('Apple', 'Grapes', 'Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Honeydew', 'Berries')
                then 1 else 0
           end) = 0;  -- nothing that isn't fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what you're trying to do is eliminate groups which contain items which are **not** fruits:

```
SELECT T1.ID
  FROM T1
  WHERE T1.ID NOT IN (SELECT T2.T1_ID
                        FROM T2
                        WHERE T2.VALUE NOT IN ('Apple','Grapes','Banana','Kiwi','Honeydew','Berries'))
  ORDER BY T1.ID
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9fba834061ed2ce61bb045b1f31652a)

Comment: but this will eliminate 1,2 & 4 as well.

Comment: I respectfully submit that it won't. See the dbfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more possible answer here.

You can use `EXISTS` in such cases.

```
SELECT
    T1.ID
FROM
    T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            T2
        WHERE
            T2.T1_ID = T1.ID
            AND T2.VALUE NOT IN (
                'Apple',
                'Grapes',
                'Banana',
                'Kiwi',
                'Honeydew',
                'Berries'
            )
    )
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24ba9c884c6a42a00207992015c430a7)

Cheers!!